# Create a function to get selectors like jquery does with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, nodelist

I am tired of including jquery in simple projects but I am so used to using it and I am trying to break free form my dependency on it.  I am trying to create a function that will give the same feel of getting selectors like classes and tags.  Example: `$('selector').innerHTML = ".something";`.  I have just been looping through them one by one like so:

```
var classElements = document.querySelectorAll('.something');
for (var i = classElements.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   classElements[i].innerHTML = "This Is A Div";
}
```

But I wanted to create a function where I could just loop through a selector without having to write out a for loop for everything that I want to find.  So I could just write it our like above `$('.something').innerHTML = "something";`

So far this is what I have but it will only get the first of each selector and won't get all of them.  Needless to say I am very stuck and the more I read on the subject the more confused I get.  I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction where my thinking is flawed or explain how jquery goes about doing this.  Here is my code:

```
window.getElements = function(selector) {
    var selectors = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    for (var i = selectors.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var elements = selectors[i];
    }
    return elements;
};

getElements(".something").innerHTML = "something";
```

Here is a fiddle [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/y52f4wh8/)

Comment: How often do you need to assign the same HTML to a bunch of elements at the same time?

Comment: Use slim version of jQuery that only includes the parts you want

Comment: Not matter what size list `querySelectorAll()` returns, the end of your `for` loop sets `elements` to `selectors[0]`, which you return.  So this function can only every return `selectors[0]`.

Comment: @Ryan not sure what you mean I am just using this as an example I want to be able to have the same functionality as jquery so I can get elements easily instead of writing a loop every time I want to get all the classes and tags in a document

Comment: If you want it to look exactly the same as jQuery, use jQuery.

Comment: Pass an options object to the function to perform tasks on the elements.

Comment: @guest271314 as I noted below, this could work, but only sometimes. It sort of depends on the function that you're applying. If you set it up right, it could work for some functions, but not all. And the amount of arguments would different and be applied in different ways. Sure, you could try to use the spread operator, etc. But it would get vey muddled and honestly would not be a very fluid way to achieve this goal.

Comment: If you want to break away from jQuery, then break away from it. Learn to write short, clean code in a style that uses the features you have available natively.

Comment: @thesublimeobject Which function would not work?

Comment: I may have misunderstood you. The solution @MartinWebb posted below should work well. I thought you meant something more in like with, `function something(element, { opts })`. But then you have to write-in tons of conditionals because some functions apply strings, and some nodes, and some integers, depending on what you call.

Comment: @thesublimeobject Yes, that is what was indicating. The first function written would be, for example, `.innerHTML`. Proceed from there. In essence, OP would write own library, one step at a time. It all has to be written.

Comment: I mean, yes, that's possible. I don't know if I would go about it that way, but maybe it would be fine. I think we're getting a little too technical and off-base here :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is how you would do it. I have done what you have asked which is allow you to use all the native functionality rather than coin wrappers around it. jQuery returns its own api which acts on the selectors. What I have done is create a selector which allows you to act on each element it finds

```html
window.getElements = function(selector,cb) {
    var selectors = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    [].forEach.call(selectors, cb);
};

getElements(".something", function(el){el.innerHTML = "ha"});

getElements("#one", function(el){el.style.background = "red" });
```

It takes the dom list that is found, converts it into an array and then calls your passed function where you pass your native code

Here is a fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/y52f4wh8/5/

Jquery works differently:

```html
window.jquery = function(selector,cb) {
 var selectors = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    
    function command(cb) {
    [].forEach.call(selectors, cb);
 };
    // Here we return our own api that uses the command function to act on
    // our selected list.
    return {
     html: function(str){
      command(function(el){
       el.innerHTML=str;
      });
      
     },
     bg: function(color){
      command(function(el){
       el.style.background = color; 
      });
     }
    }
};
// The jquery way!
jquery(".something").html("ha");
```

Comment: This should be amazingly fast compared to jquery!

Comment: I have added an example of how jquery works, primitive and not tested but you will get the idea. The first example is the best, it works for any native dom code will help you learn native and will be very very fast!

Comment: It will be interesting to go further and really create these do(el) and make a working demo on jsfiddle. Creating the basic selector we need.

Answer (score 2):

`getElements(".something").innerHTML = "something";`

this does not work because that your function *gets* and returns all of the elements, which is a `NodeList`, but it does not automatically apply methods to every element in the collection as jQuery does. In order to do that, you would have to convert the elements to an array and actually call the function on each element using a loop or some other function.

**EDIT**: To be clear, you cannot just call `NodeList.innerHTML = ''` on a NodeList because `innerHTML` is applied to one element. jQuery internally takes care of **BOTH** of the collecting of elements, and the *applying* of methods for you.

**EDIT #2**: After examining your function more carefully, I have realized there are other issues, but what I wrote above is still the basis from which you want to spring.

You could use something like this for getting elements?:

```
function getElements(elements) {
    return [...querySelectorAll(elements)]
}
```

But applying functions on nodes is going to be more selective on a case-by-case basis since many of them are applied differently.

Answer (score 1):

The selector part of JQuery is called [Sizzle](https://sizzlejs.com/). It has all the functionality that you need but does not come with the other parts of JQuery.

If you would like to find out more about the javascript behind it, I recommend to take a look at the sourcefiles of Sizzle.

Comment: I think this is the opposite of what the question was asking for (selectors work; now how do I apply actions to all of the selected elements?).

Answer (score 1):

Jquery like methods without jquery.

**What is left :)**

children find parents parent closest  , next prev  before after , first last eq() , each ,.hasClass ,prop .removeProp ,val,width height

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="p-4">
    <div id="dd" class="aa p-5 border">AAAAA</div>
</div>
<script>
function cn(x=''){
    console.log(x);
}
window.$ = function(selector) {
    
    if(typeof selector=='string')
        var selectors = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    else selectors=selector;
    
    var doo = function (callback){
        [].forEach.call(selectors, callback);
        return $(selector);
    };
    
    // Here we return our own api 
    return {
        html: function(x){
            return doo(function(el){
                el.innerHTML=x;
            });
        },      
        text: function(x){
            return doo(function(el){
                el.innerText=x;
            });
        },
        bg: function(x){
            return doo(function(el){
                el.style.background = x; 
            });
        }
        ,toggleClass: function(x){
            return doo(function(el){
                let xre=new RegExp(' '+x+' ','gm');
                if( (' '+el.className+' ').match(xre)){
                    el.className = (' '+el.className+' ').replace(' '+x+' ',x).trim();
                }else{
                    el.className = el.className+' '+x;
                }
            });
        }
        ,addClass: function(x){//
            return doo(function(el){
                el.className = el.className.trim()+' '+x;
            });
        }
        ,removeClass: function(x){//
            return doo(function(el){
                el.className = (' '+el.className+' ').replace(' '+x+' ',x).trim();
            });
        }
        
        ,attr: function(x,y){
            return doo(function(el){
                el.setAttribute(x,y);
            });
        }           
        ,removeAttr: function(x){
            return doo(function(el){
                el.removeAttribute(x);
            });
        }           
        ,data: function(x,y){
            return doo(function(el){
                el.setAttribute('data-'+x,y);
            });
        }       
        ,remove: function(x){
            return doo(function(el){
                el.remove();
            });
        }
        ,ac: function(x){return $(selector).addClass(x)}
        ,rc: function(x){return $(selector).removeClass(x)}
        ,tc: function(x){return $(selector).toggleClass(x)}
        ,yours: function(x){
            return doo(function(el){
                //bla bla
            });
        }
    }
};


$(".aa").addClass('bg-primary text-white rounded m-4').html("BBBBBBBBB BBBBBBBBBBB BBBBBBBBBBB")
</script>
```

Comment: What is left you say? Returning the elements of a selector to store in a variable to use in a normal JS function. eg. var someStuff = $(".aa"); alert(someStuff.length);

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is essentially a wrapper object for `NodeList` which adds more functionality to DOM operations. If you want to create your own wrapper object which defines functions for bulk versions of all the [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element) API, you are free to do so, but then you might as well use jQuery or some derivative.

If you want an extremely lightweight proxy object for doing bulk operations on DOM elements, there is the [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) object in ES6 which can make this very easy to do, but has no IE support.

```js
const $ = function(selector) {
  const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  return new Proxy(nodeList, {
    set: function(target, property, value) {
      for (let i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {
        target[i][property] = value;
      }
    },
    get: function(target, property) {
      return target[0] && target[0][property];
    }
  });
};

console.log($('p').innerHTML);
$('p').innerHTML = 'Bulk assignement!';
```

```html
<p>A B C</p>
<p>1 2 3</p>
<p>Do Re Mi</p>
```

Comment: Note `$("div")` would return `Proxy` object, not `Target`:`NodeList` if no `<div>` elements are found in `document` `console.log($("div")) //{
  "length": undefined,
  "item": undefined,
  "keys": undefined,
  "values": undefined,
  "entries": undefined,
  "forEach": undefined
}` at stacksnippets, `Proxy` object at `console`

Comment: @guest271314 I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Is the `console` output all you're worried about?

Answer (score 0):

An approach which would be best avoided is to define a setter for `innerHTML` on `NodeList`.

```js
Object.defineProperty(NodeList.prototype, 'innerHTML', {
  set(text) {
    [...this].forEach(elt => elt.innerHTML = text);
  }
});

const $ = selector => document.querySelectorAll(selector);

$('.foo').innerHTML = "it works";
```

```html
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
```